# pyspark:Get columns based on other records

Tags: python, join, pyspark

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
membershipAccountNbr            cntryRetailChannelCustId
111590058               1010015900581000010101
214100897               1010041008972100010101
104100897               1010041008971000010101
```

And another one that looks like this:

```
membershipAccountNbr    parentMembershipNbr
111590058                   111590058
214100897                   104100897
```

My goal is to have it look like:

```
membershipAccountNbr parentMembershipNbr parentCustId
111590058               111590058    1010015900581000010101
214100897               104100897    1010041008971000010101
```

I tried using joins but they are giving an ambiguity error. I am new to Pyspark so please help.

Answer (score 1):

Assume `df1` is,

```
+--------------------+------------------------+
|membershipAccountNbr|cntryRetailChannelCustId|
+--------------------+------------------------+
|           111590058|    10100159005810000...|
|           214100897|    10100410089721000...|
|           104100897|    10100410089710000...|
+--------------------+------------------------+
```

And `df2`,

```
+--------------------+-------------------+
|membershipAccountNbr|parentMembershipNbr|
+--------------------+-------------------+
|           111590058|          111590058|
|           214100897|          104100897|
+--------------------+-------------------+
```

Then you run,

```
df1.join(df2, on="membershipAccountNbr", how="right").select(
    col("membershipAccountNbr"),
    col("parentMembershipNbr"),
    col("cntryRetailChannelCustId").alias("parentCustId"),
).show()
```

The result will look like this,

```
+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
|membershipAccountNbr|parentMembershipNbr|        parentCustId|
+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
|           111590058|          111590058|10100159005810000...|
|           214100897|          104100897|10100410089721000...|
+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: That's what i tried doing but it gives out ambiguity error. And asks me to enable cross join